# Unable to login to the RabbitMQ using guest

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

I have the following issue. I deleted the guest user and now basically I cant login to rabbitmq using guest-guest.

I have tried the following things:

1) I did uninstall the service and install it again. It didn't work. It worked for some other colleagues but it didn't work for me. I have tried to uninstall/install nearly 10 times. I can see the service disappearing and readded. Still no success

2) Config file. The config file resides in the following location :
C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.5.1\etc\rabbitmq.

I removed the comments from the following setting :

It was like that
**%% {loopback_users, []},**

and now it is 
**{loopback_users, []},**

still no success. I restart the service every time i modify the config file but still no success. It was working before I delete the guest user. Does anyone know what else could I do or what am i doing wrong??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try again but with the config file found in:

```
C:\Users\<<Username>>\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ
```

For environment changes to take effect on Windows, the service must be re-installed. It is not sufficient to restart the service.

You can re-install from Start Menu > RabbitMQ Server > RabbitMQ Service - re(install)